# Forced Matrix Plan Data fetching issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on Forced Matrix plan website. It is 2X8 Matrix. Here user can add 2 frontline on its first level and 4 on its second level and so on. 
Now i am find the way in mysql that will satisfy my condition.
my condition is that search sponsor left and right leg anf if empty then insert new member under that sponsor and if not then search sponsor's member left and right leg and so on.

Hope you understand well.
Here is screenshort of my table data where i am saving the data with relation of sponsor and member with position.

[image]

Comment: so where is code you have already tried? that seems more of a story than a question

Comment: I want logic to solve my problem then i will code.

Comment: Why you giving my question minus point, if you dont understand then you can ask again or leave it but why you discourage my question.

Comment: Here's why I'm downvoting this question: you haven't written any code yet and ask others to do it for you. That's not how it works. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Solution does not means all code. solution means just idea and if you can not help anyone then leave it  but don't assume that people are thinking as like you.

Comment: you expects all code so that you are saying this because i want just idea if you have better way then you can tell me.

Comment: Asking for ideas is **off-topic**, that's all there is to it. People will provide solutions to those who tried things before and really are stuck, not just do things for people. The least you could of done is showed us some example code of checking and inserting and summarised what you where trying to achieve and asked for help.

Answer (score 0):

> Please, for future notice, provide code or/and ideas that **you** have already tried. This is not the place to just ask people to do things for you.

```
class Database
{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example","user","pass");
    }

    public function is_Empty($left,$right)
    {
        $search = $this->db
                       ->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... OR ...");
        $search->execute(array(
                       ':left' => $left,
                       ':right' => $right
                 ));
        if($prepare->fetchAll() == null)? return false : return true;
    }
}
```

The above code explains the principle, we're checking firstly if the person exists by using an SQL statement. Once the PDO executes the SQL query, it will return an Object. If the Object is `null` then we know that the user does not exist so we return `false`, if it does exist, we return `true`.

You can then do something like so:

```
class DatabaseExtension extends Database
{
    public function insert($name,$right, ect...)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO...");
    }
}
```

It can be called and used from `$_GET` requests or `$_POST` requests from a HTML web form which sends to a handler PHP file like so:

```
$dbHandler = new Database;
$dbHandler->inserting = new DatabaseExtension;
if($dbHandler->is_Empty($_GET['left'],$_GET['right']):
    $dbHandler->insert($_GET['name'],$_GET['right'],etc...);
else:
    echo "Sorry, this sponsor is already filled...";
endif;
```

> This code is **NOT** exact and will not be your *solution*. It is to give you an idea scope to solve your problem.

Also note that is method is very *Object-Orientated* so if you're unfamiliar with any of this code or the use of Classes, I suggest you research before you create another post like: `"What is a Class, Please make this for me."`

There are plenty of other Connection protocols/API's you can use rather than PDO although I'd recommend PDO due to both SQLi,SQL (and if you're just plain... urgh...) ODBC becoming very depreciated in newer versions of PHP.